# How do I extend my classpath to run a .jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to run an executable jar file for the agent-based modeling program called SeSAm (shell for simulated agent systems... wordpress can be found [here](https://multiagentsimulation.com/)). I have downloaded the zip file and subsequently unzipped the file and I used command prompt to try and run it.

I have changed my directory to the folder with the jar file in it, and when I use the command to run the file (java -jar SeSAm.jar) it throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Please extend your classpath with: null
        at sesam.util.jarclassloader.ClassLoaderExtender.addToClassPath(ClassLoaderExtender.java:140)
        at sesam.util.jarclassloader.ClassLoaderExtender.addToClassPath(ClassLoaderExtender.java:99)
        at sesam.gui.mas.application.SeSAm.extendClasspath(SeSAm.java:157)
        at sesam.gui.mas.application.SeSAm.main(SeSAm.java:141)
```

I have no formal education or training in computer programming so please excuse me if this is a trivial question or has a very obvious fix that is alluding me. I'd appreciate any help on how to fix this issue.

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Are you using Windows?  Windows likes to lie and present a .zip file as if it’s a folder, but it very much is not.  Make sure you have actually extracted the .zip file (that is, right-click on the zip file and choose one the “Extract” items in the context menu), then try your java -jar command again.

Comment: It is difficult to analyze from afar, but if "sesam.util.whatsit*" is mentioned, then at least the jar file is readable and executing. Unusual for java jar files, there is a specialized classLoader. My best guess is, that this thing tries to find other files that you have not downloaded or are not in the place it is looking for them.

Comment: This is a question about the specific software you're trying to run, because it's a problem in SeSAm.jar, you'll have to read the documentation for that to learn how to launch it. That error shows the java -jar command was successful and the program started, but sesam doesn't like how you opened it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of its use of Reflection, SeSAm only works with Java 8.

Make sure you're using Java 8 to run it. You can verify what version of java you have by running

`java -version`
in command prompt.